# can't commit to git / github

Tags: git, github, repository

So I just opened an account on github, and trying to submit (checkin / commit/ whatever...) a project to a new repo.

I followed the following steps:

- create a repo on the web
- followed those steps from the web:

Next steps:

```
mkdir PROJECT
cd PROJECT
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/PROJECT.git
git push -u origin master
```

When I run `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/PROJECT.git` I get the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Any ideas? In any case, I can't clone this project - it's empty on the repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that when you ran the 'git remote add' command you're not in a directory which is a git repository.  I would only expect that to happen if you're not in the directory where you did the 'git init'.  Did all of previous git commands succeed?   Did you remove the .git directory before you did the 'git remote add' or cd out of the PROJECT directory?  Did you just run the 'git remote add' in another directory?

Can you cut and paste a transcript of what you've done so we can help determine what went awry?

Comment: This suggestion seems good.  The only other addendum that I can think of is to make sure that the github project _exists_ and that the name is _exactly_ the same.

Comment: ashays - yes, but this error is client side and will only occur if git is run outside of a git repository.  That is a good thing for Christian to validate...once he's past this issue.

Comment: And being outside the directory is an indication that the OP didn't exactly follow those steps.

Comment: Now I have this problem with pushing:   Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ 
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ pwd
/Users/itairam/Desktop/testLocation
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/itairam/Desktop/testLocation/.git/
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ git commit -m 'first commit'
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit

Comment: #
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# testLocation.xcodeproj/
# testLocation/
# testLocationTests/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ git remote add origin git@github.com:itairam/testLocation.git
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:itairam/testLocation.git'
Itai-Rams-MacBook-Air:testLocation itairam$

Comment: @TommyG: you need to `git add` first, then `git commit`, and then your `git push origin master` will work.